# Как сделать отправляемые сообщения ботов жирным шрифтом?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на C# и не знаю как сделать сообщение ответа бота жирным, очень надо) Помогите!

Comment: Поставьте тег или напишите в вопросе для чего вам бот кстати))

Comment: @Anton Nikolaev, я пишу простенького бота для игры в Орёл или Решка. Проблему с шрифтами я как раз решил с помощью тегов <b>ТЕКСТ</b>, ParseMode.Html. А вот проблемку с обработкой команд с эмоджи ещё не решил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто [загуглите](http://chuvyr.ru/2017/12/telegram-bold-italic-code-link-etc.html) разметку для текста в телеграм и отправляйте обычный текст с заранее добавленными спец. символами типа:

```
**жирный текст**

__курсив__

`код`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Холмс, но как? Как вы узнали, что речь о Телеграм?

Comment: я ему с прошлым вопросом по боту помогал @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Я забыл указать, что бот для ТГ)

Comment: Отметьте решение галочкой, если помогло

Comment: Через @ обращайтесь к собеседнику: @ДмитрийСтепанов, по умолчанию уведомления о сообщениях получает только автор поста, под которым коммент.